# how to manipulate data of observable type in angular2

Tags: angular, observable

I am new angular2 so please ignore if you find it the basic question.

I have a variable of type `Observable`

```
users: Observable<User[]>;
```

and in the constructor, I am filling it

```
constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private userService: UserService) {
        this.users = this.userService.getAllUsers();
}
```

Now I want to manipulate/iterate the data of `this.users`. How can I do that?

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: Can you add the code of the method getAllUsers(). In any case, take a look at how Observables are managed, maybe starting from the http client documentation on angular.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` or any other of the long list of available operators.

You need to subscribe to execute the observable, otherwise it won't do anything. You can also use `.forEach(...)`, `.toArray()`, (and others) instead of `subscribe()`:

```
constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private userService: UserService) {
        this.users = this.userService.getAllUsers()
        .map(val => val + 'xxx')
        .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

See also https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: It is often preferable to subscribe implicitly with the `async` pipe in templates, which avoids the need to remember the subscription and unsubscribe. BTW, it is usually better to do this kind of thing in `ngOnInit` rather than in the constructor.

Comment: i have decalred private users:[{value:0,label:'sd'}]; and using subscribe this.userService.getAllUsers()
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.forEach(element => {
                    this.users.push({ value: element.id, label: element.firstName });
                });
            })   but it is showing error in console "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: a new issue with subscribe

Comment: `users: Observable<User[]>;` should be `users:User[] = [];`